# Cannot make Slickgrid basic example work on Jsfiddle

Tags: slickgrid, jsfiddle

Trying to mimic http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example1-simple.html on  http://jsfiddle.net/mejo/u5S8T/1/ but it is not working. What is wrong?

HTML:

```
    <table width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" width="50%">
      <div id="myGrid" style="width:600px;height:500px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
      <h2>Demonstrates:</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>basic grid with minimal configuration</li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
    var grid;
  var columns = [
    {id: "title", name: "Title", field: "title"},
    {id: "duration", name: "Duration", field: "duration"},
    {id: "%", name: "% Complete", field: "percentComplete"},
    {id: "start", name: "Start", field: "start"},
    {id: "finish", name: "Finish", field: "finish"},
    {id: "effort-driven", name: "Effort Driven", field: "effortDriven"}
  ];

  var options = {
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    enableColumnReorder: false
  };

  $(function () {
    var data = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      data[i] = {
        title: "Task " + i,
        duration: "5 days",
        percentComplete: Math.round(Math.random() * 100),
        start: "01/01/2009",
        finish: "01/05/2009",
        effortDriven: (i % 5 == 0)
      };
    }

    grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are missing references to required `js` files,

```
jquery-1.7.min.js
jquery.event.drag-2.2.js
slick.core.js
slick.grid.js
```

Comment: I think only one missing is http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.min.js and question is now where to get that one?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u5S8T/2/ contains now working external resources thank you. However Slickgrid example is still not working, what next?

Comment: You have added the resources to fiddle but have not included in page.To make it work. Add script to html section as follows `<script src="http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/slick.core.js"></script>`